# Google colab, pip install macest

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory

I would like to install the macest package in google colab. For this purpose, I use the command pip install macest but during installation I receive this error:

```
Collecting macest
  Downloading macest-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting matplotlib==3.1.1 (from macest)
  Downloading matplotlib-3.1.1.tar.gz (37.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 37.8/37.8 MB 23.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting numpy==1.19.0 (from macest)
  Downloading numpy-1.19.0.zip (7.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.3/7.3 MB 23.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

There is additional advice on their website on how to install it, but I don't know how to do it in practice:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements_notebooks.txt
pip install macest
```